# About a type of permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, linear-orders

How many permutations are there on the set $\{1,2, \cdots, n\}$ ($n\geq 3$), such that any three elements are not in increasing or decreasing order? For example, for $n=3$ we have $(1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1)$ and $(3,1,2)$. For $n=4$, we have $(2,1,4,3), (2,4,1,3), (3,1,4,2)$ and $(3,4,1,2)$.
I believe that, for $n\geq 5$, there are no such permutations.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem

Comment: @SamHopkins corrected link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem

Comment: The statement is that every sequence of length $\ge (r-1)(s-1)+1$ has either an increasing (= non-decreasing) sequence of length $\ge r$ or a decreasing subsequence of length $\ge s$. In particular every sequence of length $\ge (r-1)^2+1$ has a monotonic subsequence of length $\ge r$.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you!

Comment: @YCor Thank you!